# Sass function for grid

Tags: html, css, sass

I've created a Sass grid for a panel, how can I modify this using a Sass function or a Sass loop? Is it possible to use the `each` function? How would I implement it? I am using the Foundation Zurb 6 grid mixin.

```
.#{$id}{
 @at-root .#{$columns}{
  // padding: 0 !important;
  &-12{
   @include grid-column;
  }
  &-11{
   @include grid-column(11 of 12);

  }
  &-10{
   @include grid-column(10 of 12);
  }
  &-9{
   @include grid-column(9 of 12);
  }
  &-8{
   @include grid-column(8 of 12);
  }
  &-7{
   @include grid-column(7 of 12);
  }
  &-6{
   @include grid-column(6 of 12);
  }
  &-5{
   @include grid-column(5 of 12);
  }
  &-4{
   @include grid-column(4 of 12);
  }
  &-3{
   @include grid-column(3 of 12);
  }
  &-2{
   @include grid-column(2 of 12);
  }
  &-1{
   @include grid-column(1 of 12);
  }
}

@include breakpoint (medium){

&-medium{
  &-12{
   @include grid-column;
  }
  &-11{
   @include grid-column(11 of 12);

  }
  &-10{
   @include grid-column(10 of 12);
  }
  &-9{
   @include grid-column(9 of 12);
  }
  &-8{
   @include grid-column(8 of 12);
  }
  &-7{
   @include grid-column(7 of 12);
  }
  &-6{
   @include grid-column(6 of 12);
  }
  &-5{
   @include grid-column(5 of 12);
  }
  &-4{
   @include grid-column(4 of 12);
  }
  &-3{
   @include grid-column(3 of 12);
  }
  &-2{
   @include grid-column(2 of 12);
  }
  &-1{
   @include grid-column(1 of 12);
  }
}
}
   @include breakpoint (large){
  &-large{
  &-12{
   @include grid-column;
  }
  &-11{
   @include grid-column(11 of 12);

  }
  &-10{
   @include grid-column(10 of 12);
  }
  &-9{
   @include grid-column(9 of 12);
  }
  &-8{
   @include grid-column(8 of 12);
  }
  &-7{
   @include grid-column(7 of 12);
  }
  &-6{
   @include grid-column(6 of 12);
  }
  &-5{
   @include grid-column(5 of 12);
  }
  &-4{
   @include grid-column(4 of 12);
  }
  &-3{
   @include grid-column(3 of 12);
  }
  &-2{
   @include grid-column(2 of 12);
  }
  &-1{
   @include grid-column(1 of 12);
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try several loops:

```scss
.#{$id} {
  @at-root .#{$columns} {
    @for $column from 1 through 12 {
      &-#{$column} { @include grid-column(#{$column} of 12); }
    }
  }

  @include breakpoint (medium) {
    &-medium {
      @for $column from 1 through 12 {
        &-#{$column} { @include grid-column(#{$column} of 12); }
      }
    }
  }

  @include breakpoint (large) {
    &-large {
      @for $column from 1 through 12 {
          &-#{$column} { @include grid-column(#{$column} of 12); }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you can create list of breakpoints and loop through them, but it will make styles less readable.

Comment: yes it's look great, but there is foundation error.
Error: argument `$number` of `percentage($number)` must be a number

Comment: can you update question with your's full mixin and example of calling it?